# Heatmap with Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, graphite, apache-zeppelin

I have just started using Spark Streaming and done few POCs. It is fairly easy to implement. I was thinking of presenting the data using some smart graphing & dashboarding tools e.g. Graphite or Grafna, but they don't have heat-maps. I also looked at [Zeppelin](http://zeppelin-project.org/) , but unable to found any heat-map functionality. 
Could you please suggest any data visualization tools using Heat-map and Spark streaming.

Comment: We have heatmap but no Spark integration as of today.

http://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/visualization/widgets/treemap-widget/

The treemap is fairly configurable, for example, size and value of each rectangle can be mapped to different series. As a result, rectangles get resized and re-colored as new data comes in.

How difficult is to fetch data from Spark? Is it spark streaming or sql?

Comment: @SergeiRodionov Its spark streaming, as I need to update heatmap realtime, Is there any way to send data directly from spark streaming to the above tool.

Comment: Can you stream data out over tcp/udp, for example by sending a line command such as `series e:entity-name m:metric-name=123`?

Comment: Yes I can write over TCP/UDP , please tell me how can I visualize in Heat Map?

Comment: Can you post some input data here or on github, e.g. a set of measurements: metric name, value, time. I'll insert it into a test instance via tcp and publish a sample heatmap. If it works as expected, you can then install the db yourself and rerun the example locally, streaming data into the database and viewing it on the heatmap .

Comment: @SergeiRodionov, I talked to Heinrich and he explained me nicely about the steps involved, but the requirement is I have to show heatmap on world's map. And world map is currently not supported in Axibase

Answer (score 3):

In Stratio we work all the time with heatmaps that takes the data from spark. All you need is the combination of stratio-viewer http://www.stratio.com/datavis/kbase/article/map-widget/ and stratio-sparkta http://docs.stratio.com/modules/sparkta/development/about.html.

Disclaimer: I work for Stratio

Comment: The links are broken.